# ImportError: libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: python, gcc

I am trying to install tesseract bindings for python from tesseract-ocr but I get the following error after installation:

```
----> 1 import tesserocr
      2 
ImportError: /home/dsgoodri/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib/libtesseract.so.3)
```

I used the repository here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserocr
I am on Ubuntu 16.04LTS with anaconda for Python 2.7. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me...

```
conda install libgcc
```

from https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/483

Comment: ```conda install libgcc==5.2.0```